# How to insert images into a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, command

I want to update image column and insert image this command.

```
INSERT INTO table_tbl (image)
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:Desktop\ımage\image.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) image
```

How can I do?

Comment: The error clearly states that you do not have access to the image. You may need to run your application in an elevated state, in other means as admin.

Comment: If that SQL Server is running on a remote server machine, the image **must be** on that **remote server's** `C:\` drive - not yours

Comment: No this image don't remote server.Works on my own computer and admin.

Comment: You might to reconsider storing the images in the database. This is often a bad idea, especially if the images are retrieved frequently. You end up retrieving the image and persisting it to a temp folder so you can send it to the front end just to throw it away again. More often than not storing a file name and path is a better solution. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's not ok to write path like that. Add backslash and chage the name of "ımage" folder if it's a typo.  Try: 'C:\Desktop\image\image.jpg'

Comment: Is this just a random guess? It seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: My reputation is not enough to write comments yet. I think, It's reasonable guess, but I don't know if it works for the asker. Anyway, that's the first thing I'd improve in that code

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. It would be better if you explained what was wrong in the original. It took me several times reading this to notice that you added the missing backslash.

Comment: I added backslash

Answer (score 0):

You either made a typo in path specification - `C:Desktop` missing a backslash or a SQL Server service user do not have enough rights to access the file.
You may lookup service account using `services.msc` snapin and check whether it have enough rights issuing command like `icacls.exe <YOUR_FILE_OR_FOLDER>`. If there are no `(R)`, `(IR)`, `(IF)` or `(F)` then it could not read the file.
Try grant `Read` access for a service user.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that FILESTREAM  is enabled on the sql server database that you are using   and you can run this script..

```
 INSERT INTO table_tbl Values (
   NEWID(),"New Image",
       (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:Desktop\ımage\image.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB)
      As Fs))
```